# How do I achieve the outcome of call check_shipments;

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, cursors

Hello I want to achieve the outcome of call check_shipments;

[image]

Table Definitions:

[image]

How do I achieve the said storedprocedure with cursors using this code:
Please tell me what should I change within the code

```sql
DELIMITER $$

CREATE PROCEDURE check_shipments()
BEGIN
DECLARE no_more_products int DEFAULT 0;
DECLARE p_id int DEFAULT 0;
DECLARE ship_times int DEFAULT 0;
DECLARE cur_shipments CURSOR FOR
    SELECT prod_id FROM shipments;
DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND
    SET no_more_products = 1;
CREATE table IF NOT EXISTS products_Info(prod_id int, prod_shipments int);
OPEN cur_shipments;
FETCH cur_shipments INTO p_id;
REPEAT
    SELECT count(prod_id) INTO ship_times FROM shipments where prod_id = p_id;
    IF ship_times > 0 THEN
        INSERT INTO products_Info VALUES(p_id, ship_times);
    END IF;
    FETCH cur_shipments INTO p_id;
UNTIL no_more_products = 1 END REPEAT;
CLOSE cur_shipments;
SELECT * FROM products_Info;
drop table products_Info;
END $$

DELIMITER ;
```

But the outcome of my storedprocedure is like this:

[image]

Help is muchly appreaciated since I am still new to learning database stuff.

Comment: please post table definitions and sample data and required output AS TEXT

Comment: We do not work with photos. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: @Kendle I added table definitions

Comment: You add photos again. Do you want us to recognize the code text? Post this everything as well-formatted textual SQL code and tables. Table definition must be provided as CREATE TABLE, sample data as INSERT INTO.

Comment: Do not use REPEAT in SP - it is inconvenient. Use `LOOP` statement and `IF [flag | condition] THEN LEAVE LOOP`. This allows you to have a lot of leaving points with different leaving conditions used (for example, detected by different handlers or explicit conditional statements). In your case this allows to have only one FETCH statement also.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We want to count the number of lines with each id so we use

```
 INSERT INTO products_Info VALUES(p_id, 1)
>                ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE 
>                prod_shipments = prod_shipments + 1;
```

> ```
> DELIMITER $$ 
>
> CREATE PROCEDURE check_shipments()
> BEGIN
> DECLARE no_more_products int DEFAULT 0;
> DECLARE p_id int DEFAULT 0;
> DECLARE ship_times int DEFAULT 0;
> DECLARE cur_shipments CURSOR FOR
>     SELECT prod_id FROM shipments;
> DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND
>     SET no_more_products = 1;
> CREATE table IF NOT EXISTS products_Info(
>        prod_id int primary key, 
>        prod_shipments int);
> OPEN cur_shipments;
> FETCH cur_shipments INTO p_id;
> REPEAT
>     SELECT count(prod_id) INTO ship_times FROM shipments where prod_id = p_id;
>     IF ship_times > 0 THEN
>         INSERT INTO products_Info VALUES(p_id, 1)
>            ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE 
>            prod_shipments = prod_shipments + 1;
>     END IF;
>     FETCH cur_shipments INTO p_id;
> UNTIL no_more_products = 1 END REPEAT;
> CLOSE cur_shipments;
> SELECT * FROM products_Info;
> drop table products_Info;
> END $$
>
> DELIMITER ;
> ```

> ```
> call check_shipments
> ```
>
> ```
> prod_id | prod_shipments
> ------: | -------------:
>       1 |              3
>       2 |              2
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=c7c984dd21441dc047fe9645790f2bae)*

Answer (score 1):

You don't need a procedure for this. A query with a `count()` and a `group by` clause will give you what you want:

```
SELECT prod_id, count(prod_id) as prod_shipments 
  FROM shipments 
  group by prod_id 
  order by prod_id;
```

Result:

| prod_id | prod_shipments |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 3 |
| 2 | 2 |

Comment: What I need is into a stored procedure and cursors cause I am still learning, can you check my storedprocedure then?

Answer (score 1):

DECLARE cur_shipments CURSOR FOR
SELECT prod_id FROM shipments;

loads 5 rows to cursor, you loop 4 times, but insert 5 times because first fetch is outside loop and since there is no primary/unique key on pid 5 rows are inserted..

You could

DECLARE cur_shipments CURSOR FOR
SELECT DISTINCT prod_id FROM shipments;

so cursor only contains 2 rows

or

add primary key to products shipment drop the select (count)... statement and change the insert to an insert on duplicate key

```
 REPEAT
    
                INSERT INTO products_Info(prod_id ,prod_shipments) VALUES(p_id, 1)
    ON DUPLICATE key update prod_shipments = prod_shipments + 1;
    
        FETCH cur_shipments INTO p_id;
    UNTIL no_more_products = 1 END REPEAT;
```

Comment: I will try this one